# Discrete Logarithm in the generic group model is hard - Theorem by Shoup

Tags: discrete-logarithm, ggm

In Shoups well-known paper [Lower bounds for Discrete Logarithms and Related Problems](https://www.shoup.net/papers/dlbounds1.pdf) he proves that the Discrete Logarithm Problem is hard in the generic group model (if group operation and inverse are the only computations that can be performed on group elements). Theorem 1 in the paper says that the probability that a generic algorithm $A$ solves this problem is bounded by $\mathcal{O}(m^2/p)$ (m is the number of oracle queries, p the prime group order). The part that I don't understand is the following:

If we insist that $A$ succeed with probability bounded by a positive constant (e.g., 1/2) to the below, this theorem translates into a lower bound $\Omega(\sqrt{p})$ of the number of group operations queried by $A$.

Can someone explain this conclusion to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $K$ be the constant (which doesn't depend of $p$) such that the probability is bounded by $K\frac{m^2}{p}$. (a such $K$ exists by definition of $\mathcal{O}$).

It means that if an adversary solves the discrete logarithm problem with probability more than $\frac{1}{2}$, we obtain.

$$K\frac{m^2}{p}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$.

It implies that

$$m\geq \sqrt{\frac{p}{2K}} $$

Thus we deduce that $m$ -which is in fact a function of $p$, is lower bounded by $K'\sqrt{p}$, with $K':=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2K}}$ a constant which doesn't depend of $p$.

It's equivalent to write $m\in \Omega(\sqrt{p})$ (according to the [Knuth notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

Notice now that $\sqrt{p}$ is exponential in the size of the input, and you will deduce that any generic adversary is not efficient against DLog.

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)